# Is it possible to achieve both bonus objectives simultaneously in Level 3-7?

Tags: transmission

This is a particular level in the science museum game [Transmission](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lojugames.games.transmission).

The puzzle game comes with additional objectives to simple completion (fill all empty cubes), that in this instance are 'Do not cross the streams' and 'leave a spare packet on the star'.

Are these objectives supposed to be solvable simultaneously? I can solve for them independently and the progress mode shows this as collection of all available Stars (or points), but as a puzzle game it's unclear to me if there is an additional layer of difficulty, that if solving all elements simultaneously, that is possible on this and other puzzles as the game continues.

[image: Transmission level 3-7]

Comment: What are the rules? How do you solve this puzzle?

Comment: @pinckerman you have to move the glowy cubes around by drawing lines between the larger shapes filling all the hollow cubes. Cubes flow along the line filling the empty spaces. Squares terminate the flow. Circles do not.